# How to find entries that happened in a specific time range?

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this (this is sample data) :

```
 user (int) | credits (int) | time (timestamp as bigint)
 42         | 1000          | 1482015600 (18/12/2016 0:00:00)
 42         | 1000          | 1482019200 (18/12/2016 1:00:00)
 84         | 1000          | 1482022800 (18/12/2016 2:00:00)
 84         | 1000          | 1482120000 (19/12/2016 5:00:00)
 42         | 1000          | 1482130800 (19/12/2016 8:00:00)
```

A lottery on my site had a problem and some users were able to play more than one time a day (I have a theoretical limit of 1 play every 24h).
I want to find every entries that should not have been there.

In my example we can see that user 42 cheated, cause the first two entries are him playing two times in a range of 24h. He played at midnight and 1AM.
Player 84 did not cheat, he waited more than 24h to play.
On 19/12/2016, player 42 played again but this time it's not a cheat, cause his last valid play was more than 24h before.

Is there a way to do it purely in SQL ? Or should I bring up PHP and iterate over all my users and well... write an awful script ?
Thanks !

Comment: Please post some sample data in the question

Comment: What value you are storing in time column? If they are unix timestamp you can compare the diff between two time for a single user to the timestamp diff  equal to 24 hours

Comment: I've added some sample data and reformulated my example. thanks for you time !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    user, credits, time
FROM
    (SELECT 
        t1.*,
            CASE
                WHEN @user = user THEN time - @time
                ELSE 0
            END < 24 * 60 * 60 flag,
            @user:=user,
            @time:=time
    FROM
        (SELECT 
        *
    FROM
        your_table
    ORDER BY user , time) t1
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @user:=- 1, @time:=- 1) t2) t
WHERE
    flag = 1;
```

`flag` column is set to 1 based whether the difference between this time and last time was less than 24 hours.

The method uses user defined variables to keep track of last `time` for each user, and then finds difference between this `time` and last `time`. Remember that the `order by` clause is very critical for it to work.

Comment: You sir, saved my day. This seems to work perfectly.
Could you maybe explain me how you've done ?

I'll make my question "solved" when I'm ended checking everything up but a huge thanks to you.

Comment: @nsierra- added some explanation in the question.